# IE not redirecting Location header correctly with Unicode characters

Tags: php, internet-explorer, unicode, http-headers, location

On my site I'm sending a Location header with UTF-8 encoded Unicode data like this:

```
<?php
    header("Location: http://sr.wikipedia.org/sr/Србија");
    exit;
?>
```

In Internet Explorer it sends the user to: `http://sr.wikipedia.org/sr/Ð¡Ñ€Ð±Ð¸Ñ˜Ð°`.

Every other browser, it sends the user to `http://sr.wikipedia.org/sr/Србија`, which is

I'm running Apache 2 on Ubuntu boxes and the URLs in the Location header include the site's domain name. The site sends out `text/html; charset=utf-8` for its Content-Type.

I've tried:

- Adding the `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` directive to httpd.conf.
- Encoding the location URL using `rawurlencode()`.
- Sending `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");` before the `Location` header.
- Turning off gzip content-encoding
- Sending the URL through `utf8_encode()` and `utf8_decode()`

But I.E. still wont recognize the URL's encoding. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the header field name and you need to encode the URI path properly using [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode):

```
header("Location: http://sr.wikipedia.org/sr/".rawurlencode("Србија"));
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't think of that... works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why I left the "Location: " part out of the question... bad copy and paste job I guess :-)

Comment: @Gumbo - I am facing the same problem in c#, can you explain this on this behalf,
it will be really helpful

Comment: @user1006544 I’m not familiar with C#, but [System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect) and [System.Web.HttpUtility.Urlencode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Web.HttpUtility.Urlencode) look promising.

Comment: @Gumbo :- hey I appreciate your effort 
I will search that